ASP.NET Core 8 HTTPS Certificate Issues with Windows Host and Linux Container
I'm running Docker Desktop on Windows but using Linux containers. I'm trying to set up HTTPS in an ASP.NET Core 8 application, but getting SSL authentication failures. The certificate is generated on Windows and mounted into the Linux container.
Environment

Host OS: Windows
Docker Desktop running Linux containers
ASP.NET Core 8
Certificate generated using dotnet dev-certs https -ep %USERPROFILE%\.aspnet\https\aspnetapp.pfx -p VerySecurePassword123@! -> dotnet dev-certs https --trust

Error
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Connections[39]
2024-11-14T02:09:35.774407159Z       Connection id "0HN84A5GB7LGC" accepted.
2024-11-14T02:09:35.774414059Z dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Connections[1]
2024-11-14T02:09:35.774430660Z       Connection id "0HN84A5GB7LGC" started.
2024-11-14T02:09:35.776304532Z dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https.Internal.HttpsConnectionMiddleware[1]
2024-11-14T02:09:35.776340833Z       Failed to authenticate HTTPS connection.
2024-11-14T02:09:35.776346834Z       System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Cannot determine the frame size or a corrupted frame was received.
2024-11-14T02:09:35.776350934Z          at System.Net.Security.SslStream.GetFrameSize(ReadOnlySpan`1 buffer)
2024-11-14T02:09:35.776354134Z          at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EnsureFullTlsFrameAsync[TIOAdapter](CancellationToken cancellationToken, Int32 estimatedSize)
2024-11-14T02:09:35.776357734Z          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.PoolingAsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder`1.StateMachineBox`1.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<TResult>.GetResult(Int16 token)
2024-11-14T02:09:35.776362534Z          at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReceiveHandshakeFrameAsync[TIOAdapter](CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2024-11-14T02:09:35.776365734Z          at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2024-11-14T02:09:35.776369135Z          at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ProcessAuthenticationWithTelemetryAsync(Boolean isAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2024-11-14T02:09:35.776373135Z          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https.Internal.HttpsConnectionMiddleware.OnConnectionAsync(ConnectionContext context)
2024-11-14T02:09:35.776377135Z dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Connections[2]
2024-11-14T02:09:35.776381235Z       Connection id "0HN84A5GB7LGC" stopped.
2024-11-14T02:09:35.776534441Z dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets[7]
2024-11-14T02:09:35.776547141Z       Connection id "0HN84A5GB7LGC" sending FIN because: "The Socket transport's send loop completed gracefully."

How can I resolve this? I just need to run this using HTTPS for development purposes to test if a nuget package works on Linux. The certificate type doesn't matter or whether it’s password-protected or passwordless.
Configuration
docker-compose.yml
services:
  pr.orderservice.webapi:
    image: pr.orderservice.webapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: OrderService/PR.OrderService.WebApi/Dockerfile
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=VerySecurePassword123@!
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/aspnetapp.pfx
    ports:
      - "5000:80"
      - "44362:443"
    volumes:
      - ${USERPROFILE}\.aspnet\https:/https/:ro

Dockerfile
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER $APP_UID
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8081

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["OrderService/PR.OrderService.WebApi/PR.OrderService.WebApi.csproj", "OrderService/PR.OrderService.WebApi/"]
COPY ["BuildingBlocks/PR.BuildingBlocks.EventBus/PR.BuildingBlocks.EventBus.csproj", "BuildingBlocks/PR.BuildingBlocks.EventBus/"]
COPY ["BuildingBlocks/PR.BuildingBlocks.Common/PR.BuildingBlocks.Common.csproj", "BuildingBlocks/PR.BuildingBlocks.Common/"]
COPY ["BuildingBlocks/PR.BuildingBlocks.Testing/PR.BuildingBlocks.Testing.csproj", "BuildingBlocks/PR.BuildingBlocks.Testing/"]
COPY ["BuildingBlocks/PR.BuildingBlocks.WebCommon/PR.BuildingBlocks.WebCommon.csproj", "BuildingBlocks/PR.BuildingBlocks.WebCommon/"]
COPY ["BuildingBlocks/PR.BuildingBlocks.CustomExceptions/PR.BuildingBlocks.CustomExceptions.csproj", "BuildingBlocks/PR.BuildingBlocks.CustomExceptions/"]
COPY ["BuildingBlocks/PR.MultiTenancyServer.AspNetCore/PR.MultiTenancyServer.AspNetCore.csproj", "BuildingBlocks/PR.MultiTenancyServer.AspNetCore/"]
COPY ["BuildingBlocks/PR.MultiTenancyServer.Core/PR.MultiTenancyServer.Core.csproj", "BuildingBlocks/PR.MultiTenancyServer.Core/"]
COPY ["OrderService/PR.OrderService.Persistence.Database/PR.OrderService.Persistence.Database.csproj", "OrderService/PR.OrderService.Persistence.Database/"]
COPY ["BuildingBlocks/PR.MultiTenancyServer.EFCore/PR.MultiTenancyServer.EFCore.csproj", "BuildingBlocks/PR.MultiTenancyServer.EFCore/"]
COPY ["BuildingBlocks/PR.MultiTenancyServer.Stores/PR.MultiTenancyServer.Stores.csproj", "BuildingBlocks/PR.MultiTenancyServer.Stores/"]
COPY ["OrderService/PR.OrderService.Domain/PR.OrderService.Domain.csproj", "OrderService/PR.OrderService.Domain/"]
COPY ["OrderService/PR.OrderService.Common/PR.OrderService.Common.csproj", "OrderService/PR.OrderService.Common/"]
COPY ["OrderService/PR.OrderService.Persistence/PR.OrderService.Persistence.csproj", "OrderService/PR.OrderService.Persistence/"]
COPY ["OrderService/PR.OrderService.Services.Resilience/PR.OrderService.Services.Resilience.csproj", "OrderService/PR.OrderService.Services.Resilience/"]
COPY ["OrderService/PR.OrderService.Services/PR.OrderService.Services.csproj", "OrderService/PR.OrderService.Services/"]
COPY ["BuildingBlocks/PR.IntegrationEvents.Commons/PR.IntegrationEvents.Commons.csproj", "BuildingBlocks/PR.IntegrationEvents.Commons/"]
RUN dotnet restore "OrderService/PR.OrderService.WebApi/PR.OrderService.WebApi.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/OrderService/PR.OrderService.WebApi"
RUN dotnet build "PR.OrderService.WebApi.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "PR.OrderService.WebApi.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "PR.OrderService.WebApi.dll"]


Hi nop, I found this link and I also think this issue is related to TLS1.3. Could you kindly verified it ? And we also can set it in Program.cs, if you don't want to change the Registry Table.

What are you using to test the connection? It looks like your application thinks the incoming request is malformed.

@JasonPan, Hey, I just tried adding builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(options => {  options.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(httpsOptions =>  {   httpsOptions.SslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12;  }); }); in Program.cs, but nothing has changed. Same error message. I guess it's something else

@HansKilian, I use Firefox. Out of curiosity, I just tried with Chrome, and it worked, lol. What could possibly be causing Firefox to malform the request?

Oh, I just realized that when I click on the port in Docker Desktop, it uses HTTP by default. That's why it didn't work with Firefox - my bad. @HansKilian, feel free to post this as an answer, and hopefully it helps someone else. I've been struggling with this for two days

It looks like your application thinks the incoming request is malformed.
Make sure that you're using HTTPS when testing it.

Thank you! If you’re clicking on the port in Docker Desktop (https://i.imgur.com/Z792ryP.png) like I did, it shows it will redirect you to http:// instead of https://, which was confusing in my case. I didn’t notice that it redirected me to HTTP instead of HTTPS, especially since browsers nowadays omit the http(s):// prefix. Hopefully this helps others.
